# A signal layer is "ignored" in Altium

Tags: pcb, altium, stack-up

In Altium 20, I have the following layer stack-up. When I try to route a track on layer 6 (Signal3) it jumps to the bottom layer and continues to draw on the bottom layer. When I draw a track on bottom layer and want to change the layer with Ctrl+Shift+Mouse wheel, it ignores layer 6. It jumps to the top layer then layer 3 (Signal2) and then to bottom layer, jumping over layer 6 (signal3).

Why does Altium ignore layer 6?

[image: layer stack up]

Comment: Can you draw a test track on any layer and then change it to layer 6 in the properties panel?

Comment: I can draw a track on any layer and change it to layer 6 manually without problem. But Altium doesn't jump to layer 6 automatically.

Comment: Probably a bug, submit it to altium

Comment: I admit I don't have any other suggestions. If you do determine the cause, please post an answer.

Comment: Is there something in the rules that prevents routing on layer 6?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check in Design Rules, specifically: Routing > Routing Layers:

[image: Design Rules > Routing > Routing Layers]

Here you can define which layers you are allowed to route signals on. To be able to draw tracks on the layer you need to allow routing. Ctrl + Shift + Mouse Wheel will not allow you to switch to the layer if routing is not allowed on it.